# What is the definition of the tensor product $U⊗ V$ of two vector spaces $U$ and $V$?

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products, tensors

All I want to know is the exact definition of the vector space that is the *tensor product of two vector spaces*, say $U$ and $V$, i.e. I want to know:
- how its vectors are defined,
- how does the $+$ of two of its vectors works
- what is its scalar field,
etc.

This is what my textbook (*Mathematical Physics* by Sadri Hassani) says about this issue:

> Let $U$ and $V$ be vector spaces. On their Cartesian product, impose the scalar product and bilinearity conditions:
>   $$ α ( |u \rangle, |v \rangle) =  (α |u \rangle, |v \rangle) =  ( |u \rangle, α |v \rangle)$$
>   $$ (α_1  |u_1 \rangle + α_2  |u_2 \rangle, |v \rangle) = α_1 ( |u_1 \rangle ,|v \rangle) + α_2 ( |u_2 \rangle ,|v \rangle) $$
>   $$(α |u \rangle, β_1 |v_1\rangle+β_2 |v_2\rangle) = β_1 ( |u \rangle ,|v_1 \rangle) + β_2 ( |u \rangle ,|v_2 \rangle)$$
>
> These properties turn $U×V$ into a vector space called the tensor product of
>   $U$ and $V$ and denoted by $U⊗V$. The vectors in the tensor product space are
>   denoted by $|u \rangle⊗ |v \rangle$, or occasionally by $|uv \rangle$.

Then it goes on to introduce the basis and other stuff.
But it doesn't look right!  $ α ( |u \rangle, |v \rangle)$ , $ (α |u \rangle, |v \rangle) $ and $  ( |u \rangle, α |v \rangle)$ are (by definition)  different elements of $U×V$; how can we assume that they are equal? And imposing conditions on $U×V$ makes it a smaller set; how can we extract $U⊗ V$, which is supposedly a bigger set, out of this procedure?

Dear replier, I don't expect you to necessarily make the above definition clear for me or remain true to its notation style. It's up to you, but all I want is an accurate definition from scratch. Even a good link will do.
Thank you very much.

Comment: See the answer below for the construction. But once you believe it, forget it because the important thing about tensor products is the universal property they satisfy. See [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf)

Comment: @Chilango Thanks for your advice and the link. I had to believe it in order to feel right about forgetting it and using the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all consider a much bigger vector space obtained by taking all finite
linear combinations of elements of the form $(|v\rangle,|w\rangle)\in V \times W$ i.e,
$$\mathbb{C}(U\times V):=\left\{\sum\lambda (|u\rangle,\ v\rangle):\text{ all but finitely many }\lambda\neq0\right\}.$$

Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on this set according to your relations above:

$$ α ( |u \rangle, |v \rangle) \sim  (α |u \rangle, |v \rangle) \sim  ( |u \rangle, α |v \rangle)$$
$$ (α_1  |u_1 \rangle + α_2  |u_2 \rangle, |v \rangle) \sim α_1 ( |u_1 \rangle ,|v \rangle) + α_2 ( |u_2 \rangle ,|v \rangle) $$
$$(α |u \rangle, β_1 |v_1\rangle+β_2 |v_2\rangle) \sim β_1 ( |u \rangle ,|v_1 \rangle) + β_2 ( |u \rangle ,|v_2 \rangle).$$

The equivalence classes of this relation constitute the elements of $U\otimes V$.

Comment: Isn't a finite linear combinations of elements of the form $(|v\rangle,|w\rangle)\in V \times W$ already an element of $V \times W$? I mean: $\sum\lambda (|u\rangle, |v\rangle) =_? (\sum\lambda |u\rangle, \sum\lambda  |v\rangle)$.

Comment: @MJF only if you assume that everything is bilinear...